# How to get future object from dask bag?

Tags: dask

I need to invoke a call back function from future to perform retry logic on a task. But I don't know how to get a future object from dask bag.

For example, this is how dask bag is used

```
b = db.from_sequence(['1.dat', '2.dat', ...]).map(process_filename)
b.compute()
# I need a callback function when a task is finish with a single file to have complex retry logic
# I can get a future object from client.submit(my_args).add_done_callback(my_call_back) but I don't want to use client.submit because of large data set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get futures from bag partitions with the following:

```
from dask.distributed import futures_of

b = b.persist()
futures = futures_of(b)
```

Comment: Is there a way to get function input from a future object?